# stop audio when navigating in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-sound

I have an app that uses [React navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) to navigate, and in my app I made an audioplayer component that uses [React Native Sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound). My question is, how can I stop the audio when the user navigates to another view?

I've found the [function](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators) `onNavigationStateChange` on the navigator which is being called, but I don't know how to connect that to my audioplayers?

```
<Provider store={this.state.store}>
<AppNavigator ref={(nav) => { this.navigator = nav; }} onNavigationStateChange={()=>{console.log('now i should stop audio');}}  />
</Provider>
```